# How to insert multidimensional array fields and array rows to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to insert this kind of array to mysql using php but always failed, any kind of suggestion guys ?

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0303/FTSCY/WS95011
            [1] => 0403/FTSCY/WS95011
            [2] => 0403/FTSCY/WS95011
            [3] => 1103/FTSCY/WS95011
        )

    [total] => Array
        (
            [0] => 120825.00
            [1] => 116441.00
            [2] => 11441.00
            [3] => 350000.00
        )

    [berita] => Array
        (
            [0] => #weye
            [1] => gunadi #1441
            [2] => Kekurangan # 1441
            [3] => webreport Spulsa
        )

    [nama] => Array
        (
            [0] => ROSTRIVIA EVELYN D
            [1] => GUNADI HIDAYAT
            [2] => GUNADI HIDAYAT
            [3] => SUJOKO
        )

)
```

this is my php code :

```
$output=$VCurl->goCurl('https://ibank.klikbca.com/accountstmt.do?value(actions)=acctstmtview');
    $output= trim(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $output[0])); 
    preg_match_all('@<td width="130" bgcolor="#(.*?)"><div align="left"><font face="verdana" size="1" color="#(.*?)">(.*?)</font></div></td><td width="30" bgcolor="#(.*?)"><div align="center"><font face="verdana" size="1" color="#(.*?)">0000</font></div></td>@',  $output,$info); 
    //print_r ($info);
    foreach($info[3] as $newInfo)
    {
        preg_match_all("#TRSF E-BANKING CR<br>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br>(.*?)#",$newInfo,$data);
        if($data[2] && $data[3]){

            $dataTrf['tanggal'][] = trim($data[0][0]);
            $dataTrf['id'][] = trim($data[1][0]);
            $dataTrf['total'][]= trim($data[2][0]);
            $dataTrf['berita'][]= trim($data[3][0]);
            $dataTrf['nama'][]= trim($data[4][0]);

            $conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS) or
            die ('Error connecting to mysql');

            mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or
                    die ('Error selecting database');



            for($i = 1; $i < count($data); $i++){
                //this is where your sql goes
                $sql = "INSERT INTO bca (id, tanggal, total, berita,nama) 
                VALUES(trim($data[1][$i]),$data[2][$i], $data[3][$i], $data[4][$i], $data[5][$i]) ";

                print_r ($sql);
                mysql_query($sql) 
                        or die(mysql_error());  
            }
        }
```

I think my mistake are in looping process but i'm new to php programming, please give me a suggestion / solutions, thx

Comment: You need `'` - single quotes - encasing the $data, such as: `$data[1][$i]` becomes `'$data[1][$i]'`

Answer (score 1):

in the middle of my coding I will need of this in inserting multi array at the same time...

Here is my code...

```
  $keyid = $_POST['keyid'];
  $ksiteid = $_POST['ksiteid'];
  $lickey = $_POST['lickey'];
  $keytype = $_POST['keytype'];
  $lcontext = $_POST['lcontext'];
  $ctxparm = $_POST['ctxparm'];
  $progby = $_POST['progby'];
  $progdt = $_POST['progdt'];
  $produser = $_POST['produser'];
  $lickey = $_POST['lickey'];

  // in this section I will insert a lists of data at the same time 
  foreach($lickey as $idlk=>$lkey)
  {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO sitekeys (keyid, ksiteid, lickey, keytype, lcontext, ctxparm, progby, progdt, produser )
  VALUES ('$keyid', '$ksiteid', '$lkey', '$keytype', '$lcontext', '$ctxparm', '$progby', '$progdt',  '$produser')"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  }
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bca (id, tanggal, total, berita, nama) 
        VALUES('" . trim($data['id'][$i]) . "', '', 
        '" . $data['total'][$i] . "', 
        '" . $data['berita'][$i] . "', 
        '" . $data['nama'][$i] . "'");
```

Note: Be sure to escape the string before inserting into DB.

Comment: thx for your help, your code have no error, but the values are empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   for($i = 0; $i < count($data['id']); $i++){      

        $_id = trim($data['id'][$i]);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO bca (`id`, `tanggal`, `total`, `berita`, `nama`) ";
        $sql.= "VALUES ('{$_id}', '{$data['tanggal'][$i]}', '{$data['total'][$i]}', '{$data['berita'][$i]}', '{$data['nama'][$i]}');";

        print_r($sql);
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
    }
```

Comment: thx for your help, your code have no error, but the values are empty